# Reference Request: Proof of Early Stopping Criterion

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, references, regularization

I am looking for a proof that "Validation-based early stopping" methods work but I have no idea where to start, as I am new to this field.  Any recomendations of some rigerous papers that focus on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two seminal publications on the early stopping in ML are:

1. Zhang and Yu (2005) "*[Boosting with early stopping: Convergence and consistency](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0508276)* and
2. Yuan, Rosasco, and Caponnetto (2007) "*[On early stopping in gradient descent learning](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-006-0663-2)*".

Both are rigorous papers; they explore the matter under of early stopping within the context of gradient boosting and regularised regression respectively. There is some earlier work on regularisation for [inverse problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem). This is not formally early stopping but it relates to the concept of a solution becoming "saturated" and no longer offering better convergence rates (e.g. Neubauer (1997) "[*On converse and saturation results for Tikhonov regularization of linear ill-posed problems*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0ebe/204f654fa4f7d022b3e4a9a6a8ca18cb6ffe.pdf)").

Comment: Is there such a result for deen networks?  Since the later is for kernel methods

Comment: Not to my knowledge. There some papers with practical applications (e.g. "*[Accelerating Neural Architecture Search using Performance Prediction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.10823.pdf)*") that could be insightful though.

Comment: That's fine; but I would need something theoretically founded :)